# ImageIO is unable to write buffered image to file

Tags: java, file, jpeg, javax.imageio

I am having some problem in writing bufferedimage to `jpg` file.
in my method , i am getting a `bufferedimage` as parameter which i need to write in a file-

here is what i am doing :

```
public boolean writeToFile(BufferedImage buff,String savePath) {

        try {

            System.out.println(buff.toString());
            ImageIO.write(buff, ".jpg", new File(savePath));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
   }
```

here is what gets printed by `buff.toString()` :

```
BufferedImage@8046f4: type = 1 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=0 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 1024 height = 172 #Bands = 3 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0
```

program runs fine without any exception, but the generated jpg file size is `0 bytes`

i tried writing image without using ImageIO :

```
public boolean writeToFile(BufferedImage buff,String savePath) {



        try {

            System.out.println("got image : " + buff.toString());
            Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
            ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
            ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();


            iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            iwp.setCompressionQuality(.5f); 


            File file = new File(savePath);
            FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(file);
            writer.setOutput(output);
            IIOImage image = new IIOImage(buff, null, null);
            writer.write(null, image, iwp);
            writer.dispose();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And this works absolutely fine.

Why it is not working with ImageIO ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `.` from your format name.

```
ImageIO.write(buff, "jpg", new File(savePath));
```

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not, it's just this `".jpg"`, change it to "jpg" and it will work fine.

I had the same issue, but I looked at the [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29), and found this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html).